# How to organise unbalanced data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

This is a first post from an R/coding novice!

Essentially, I have some data which is unbalanced. Participants in my study first saw and rated every face on its own (without context). Then, in a subsequent context condition, they saw each of these 64 faces in either a positive or negative context (32 positive, 32 negative).

I was going to post a photo of the dataframe for reference, but I'm not allowed to until I have sufficient reputation, so I don't know how else I can show my dataframe?

Nevertheless, all I want to do is contrast no-context smiles with their respective smiles in a positive context, and the remaining no-context smiles with their respective smiles in a negative context. However, I haven't worked out a way of doing this without using all of the no-context trials for each comparison (when of course, I only need half of them for each)

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: Hi Samedi. Welcome to SO. Your question is quite vague. Please see this advice on how to formulate a good question https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1156245

Comment: @geotheory Thank you for your help! I would have made it much easier but I can't post a photo of my dataframe which is extremely frustrating! It would be pretty self-explanatory from that, because I don't think it is a tough question

Comment: I voted to close this question down, as it is not an actual programming question, and it is too vague for an SO topic.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Posting photos of your data is actually not a great way to share your data so that we can help you. In addition to the helpful post linked by @geotheory also look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question which has some useful tips. In short we can only take your data/code and work with it if we can easily copy+paste it, which we can't do with an image.

Comment: @qdread Ok, thank you for the advice! I will remember this in future